# Update Xampp from 10.1.36-MariaDB to 10.2 on mac os

Tags: macos, xampp, mariadb

I am looking for solution on how to update mariadb on xampp on Mac system but not found any article on that.Please help me how to update. I want "With" keyword to run a raw query that's why I am looking for update from V10.1 to V10.2. Or if there is any other way to do this please let me know

Current version is 10.1.36-MariaDB

Comment: Probably a question for ServerFault. But a quick look on the website shows that current release of xampp (7.2.27-0 / 7.3.14-0 / 7.4.2-0) ships with MariaDB 10.4.11. Why not update the whole xampp?

Comment: The `WITH` keyword (and other CTE syntax) is only available with 10.2+.  If you would like to explain the query you are trying, we might have a pre-CTE workaround.